# unable to copy clipboard to C:\ folder

Tags: c#, permissions, clipboard

I am trying to take a screenshot of my monitor, after pressing Print Screen button. With the code below I am trying to check whether there is any contents in clipboard. If so, I am trying to save it in c:. When i run the below code, it always results in "A generic error occurred in GDI+." exception. but when i use code but change the folder to "f:\" then its working fine. It looks like access permission issues with "C:\" folder. Please let me know how to enable permissions for C folder.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace Example2
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
            {
                Image screenshot = Clipboard.GetImage();
                Image mahir = screenshot;

                mahir.Save("c:\\screenshot.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you run your code on Windows Vista or later? If so you only have permissions to write as administrator in folder "c:\".

Answer (score 3):

Why save it to `c:` at all, and not somewhere more manageable, like `My Documents` or `Desktop`? Depending on where you run your program, you may or may not run into security issues trying to save directly to `c:`.

Consider using the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum to get a proper location and save the image there.

```
mahir.Save(Path.Combine(
  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "screenshot.gif"),
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Alternatively, you could try running your program with admin privileges.